# What rendering engine does google's pagespeed and mobile-friendly test use?

Tags: css, google-chrome, webkit, google-pagespeed, mobile-webkit

You'd think just "webkit", but the screenshots it shows me (and the issues it finds) are quite different to anything that I've seen via devtools device testing or using actual devices.

Is it maybe just an outdated version of webkit?

Without knowing what they're using it's hard to know how to fix the issues, and I feel they'll negatively affect my search index rankings if I don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr:**

1- You are right, it is webkit, **however**, it is a pretty much *A stripped down version of Chrome for Android*

2- **What you see** is the **default android browser**, you can **use**

[Can I Use](http://caniuse.com)

and look at "**Android Browser**" to see whether or not **your design is supported** by the "mobile view" in PageSpeed

**Long Version:**

my understanding is this:

1- The *view-port* you see **in PageSpeed** *represents* what a person using the **default browser in Android** phones would see.

2- The Default Android browser - AKA "**WebView**" -

> is based on the same code as Chrome for Android version

However,

> WebView does not have full feature parity with Chrome for Android

Source: [Google](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/overview)

Comment: Great info, thank you!  Stupid question but how can I get this browser on my phone (Google/Motorola Nexus 6).  I searched for "Android browser" in play store but couldn't find it.

Comment: You're welcome. The browser comes pre-installed with all Android phones - you don't need to download it. The name of the application is "internet" and the application icon looks like this: http://www.pocketables.com/images/2013/03/aosp-browser-icon.png

Comment: Not on Google Nexus phones, I think google chooses to put Chrome on rather than the stock browser.  I've had this phone for 2 years and have never seen such an icon, or an app called "Internet".